# jQuery/JSON autocomplete for two fields

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying out jQuery's autocomplete widget and have kind of run into a wall.  Would appreciate some input/guidance.

Essentially, I have a form where someone will type in the name of a person...jQuery will then query the database and suggest matches.  The form has two fields that need to be filled from the JSON data - the name field and a hidden ID field.  So far, I can get it to only give suggestions and fill in the name field when selected but have had no luck at getting it to update the hidden ID field.  I know I have to be missing something key from the jQuery code, but haven't figured it out.  I have tried setting values using the "select" event, but with no luck.

Here is the relevant FORM code:

```
<div id="formblock" class="stack">
    <label>Project POC: <span class="error" name="proj_poc_error" id="proj_desc_error">This field is required.</span></label>
    <input type="text" name="proj_poc" id="proj_poc">
    <input type="hidden" name="proj_poc_id" id="proj_poc_id" value="NOT SET">   
</div>
```

Here is the relevant jQuery code:

```
$(function() {

        $( "#proj_poc" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
                $.getJSON("/includes/AJAX/GetContactNames.php?callback=?", request, function(data){
                    var suggestions = [];
                    $.each(data, function(i, val){
                        suggestions.push(val.contacts);
                    });
                    response(suggestions);
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ){
                       //Should display user ID a
                       alert(ui.item.id + ui.item.contacts);

            }

        });

});
```

Here is the relevant PHP from GetContactNames.php

```
//Initiate the session
session_start(); 

//Load custom classes
    include_once ('../../ops.inc.php');

//Get the search term from GET  
    $param = $_GET['term'];

//Create new dblink class and connect to db 
    $uplink = new dblink();
        $uplink->connect();

//Create new dbcontrol class    
    $control = new dbcontrol();

//Set the query to select ID and CONCAT'd NAME from Contact Table
    $control->query = "SELECT `id`, CONCAT_WS(\" \",`firstname`,`lastname`) AS 'contacts' FROM `addressbook` WHERE `firstname` REGEXP '^$param'";

//Execute the query 
    $control->execute();

//Set an iterator value to 0    
    $i = 0;

//Get the results into array, then iterate. 
    while($row = $control->toAssocArray()){

        foreach($row as $column=>$value){
            $results[$i][$column] = $value;
        }

        $i++;

    }

//Set the response string and encode for json   
    $response = $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($results).")";

//Display the response string   
    echo $response;

//Disconnect from the database  
    $uplink->disconnect();

//Destroy classes   
    unset($uplink, $control);
```

The output of the GetContactNames.php results look like this:

```
([{"id":"1","name":"Santa Clause"},{"id":"2","name":"Joe Blow"}])
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The data structure that you build in the source function must contain objects that have a label and a value fields. The label field is what is displayed in the autocomplete menu, the value is what is going to be set as value in the text field once you select a value.

Here is an example, when searching users :

```
success: function( data ) {
            response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                return {
                label: item.username+" ("+item.firstname+" "+item.lastname+")",
                value: item.username
            };
    }
```

In this example, the displayed value will be the username + first and last names, while the value actually copied into the text field will be just the username.

Then you can do this in the select function :

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    alert(ui.item.value);
}
```

Also, in your code, I don't see where the `val.contacts` variable comes from, since in the JSON you gave, there is no "contacts " field on the objects...

Hope this helps.